# Am using php, json services while i execute below code i am getting a blank page, no data updated in database...correct me if wrong

Tags: php, html, mysql, json, web-services

## PHP

I am a beginner to web services.This is my code using php, json and mysql in restful web services in order to update the user status.Even I am not able to update the user information to the database..plz help me out...!!

```
    <?php
    
    //content header-type
    
    //header('content-type: application/json');
    
    // connect to data-base
    
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
     $dbuser = 'root';
      $dbpass = '';
       $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass); 
       if(! $conn ) 
        {
           die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
            }  
            
            //on submit action

            if(isset($_PUT['update']))
            {
    
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
    {
        $id = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ID']) ? 
        mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['HTTP_ID']) : "";
    
        $status = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_STATUS']) ? 
        mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['HTTP_STATUS']) : "";
    
        // validations of code

        if(!empty($id)){
            $qur = mysql_query("UPDATE  `miisky`.`register` SET  `status` =  '$status' WHERE  `register`.`ID` ='$id';");
            if($qur){
                $json = array("status" => 1, "msg" => "Status updated!!.");
            }else{
                $json = array("status" => 0, "msg" => "Error updating status");
            }
        }else{
            $json = array("status" => 0, "msg" => "User ID not define");
        }
    }else{
            $json = array("status" => 0, "msg" => "User ID not define");
        }
        @mysql_close($conn);
    
        /* Output header */
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($json);
    }
    ?>
```

## HTML

And hear goes my html validation part, to validate the user in order to receive the input from user and update the status of particular user.

```
<body>
  <form method = "POST" action = "update2.php">

    <h1>Please enter your user id to update your other details</h1>
    <label>ID</label>
    <input type = "text" name = "ID"><br/>
    <label>Status</label>
    <input type = "text" name = "status">
    <br/>
    <input type = "submit" name = "update">

 </form>
</body>
```

Comment: What is the response after execution? Any errors?

Comment: On execution i am getting blank page...!!

Comment: Does your execution goes inside `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "PUT")`. Try echoing inside this condition. Also print $_SERVER variable on top the page like this `echo '<pre/>'; print_r($_SERVER);`

Comment: Change `$_PUT['update']` to `$_POST['update']`

Comment: code is getting ambiguous..and echoing the condition is displaying:  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\json_services\update2.php on line 25

Comment: @Karan echo json_encode($json); is outside else but its inside if(isset($_PUT['update']))

Comment: sorry i have edited comment. There is no `$_PUT` superglobal in php. you should use `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST`

Comment: yep...dude thanks....thats a silly mistake....thanks again

Comment: I would like to know how to make it more secure one..??

Comment: PDO or should I use SSL..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML forms only support GET and POST. Only method attribute allowed GET and POST  request in html form. So you can't set PUT method type in method attribute. Change you method type in method attribute.
As per  the HTML standard, you can not.

```
 <form method = "PUT" action = "update2.php">
```

Change your method attribute e.g. GET or POST.

```
<form method = "GET" action = "update2.php">
```

Due to wrong mehtod attribute value your if condition is not coming true. You always got GET value from:-

```
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "PUT")
```

Comment: should I use..PDO and SSL..?